Did Indian kings send diplomats to foreign lands?
We know of famous Greek and possibly Chinese diplomats to Indian kingdoms, but did Indian kings send diplomats (likely Brahmins or monks) to both other kingdoms and foreign lands? What was life like for these diplomats and what were their roles? Note I want kingdoms run by Hindu rulers primarily.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

@MCW have none related to the question.

@Haridasa Then do some.

Check out the sections on "Emissaries" and "Presence in the West" in the Wikipedia article about the Edicts of Ashoka. That seems to be the only relevant source and it's not very decisive.

@BrianZ thank you

As for emissaries from Hindu rulers, I see no evidence that there were. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece%E2%80%93Ancient_India_relations

For some reason I fixated on the Greek part... as for "foreign lands" beyond the Indian subcontinent, absolutely, with SE Asia being the most noteworthy.

Nitpick: Diplomats always go to "foreign lands." And at the time, another kingdom in the subcontinent would be foreign, even if nowadays the territory of both belongs to the current country of India.

@SJuan76 I mean like another country away.
